# Какой из вариантов расстановки знаков препинания верный?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, причастный-оборот

Слова, обозначающие специфические национальные реалии, так называемая безэквивалентная лексика, передаются транскрипцией.

Слова, обозначающие специфические национальные реалии -- так называемая безэквивалентная лексика, передаются транскрипцией.

Слова, обозначающие специфические национальные реалии, -- так называемая безэквивалентная лексика, передаются транскрипцией.

Слова, обозначающие специфические национальные реалии, -- так называемая безэквивалентная лексика -- передаются транскрипцией.

Можно ли сказать передается вместо передаются? Или тогда сказуемое не будет согласовано с подлежащим?

Comment: Слова = лексика? Неужели?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Если слова «так называемый» присоединяют пояснительную конструкцию, то запятыми (или тире) выделяется весь оборот ([Словарь-справочник по пунктуации](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/687/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9)) .

Но в предложении есть также причастный оборот, который должен быть обособлен.

В четвертом варианте причастный оборот выделен запятыми, а пояснительная конструкция — тире. Это и есть, на мой взгляд, правильный ответ.

**Слова, обозначающие специфические национальные реалии, — так называемая безэквивалентная лексика — передаются транскрипцией.**

И, конечно, сказуемое согласуется с подлежащим, а не с пояснительной конструкцией. Корректно: **слова .... передаются.**

Answer (score 1):

Правилен последний вариант. Можно сначала отдельно рассмотреть упрощённый вариант предложения - без вставки о "лексике":

> Слов**а**, обозначающие специфические национальные реалии, () переда**ют**ся
>   транскрипцией.

Это обычный случай обособления запятыми причастного оборота. По отдельному правилу оформляется двумя тире *вставка* - пояснительное отступление, разбивающее грамматику исходного предложения (здесь разбивается связь подлежащего со сказуемым). В результате добавления этой вставки встречаются запятая и тире, которые по правилу стечения знаков не упрощаются отбрасыванием одного из них, а следуют как раз в таком порядке (запятая и за ней тире). http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=176