# Можно ли оформить вставку запятыми и тире по принципу симметрии?

Tags: вставная-конструкция

Вопрос касается уже рассмотренного предложения: [Какой из вариантов расстановки знаков препинания верный?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441405/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

А что если применить  в нём симметрично оформленную вставку, в принципе она разрешена правилами:

**Слова, обозначающие специфические национальные реалии, — так называемая безэквивалентная лексика, — передаются транскрипцией.**

**Почему-то чисто визуально только одна запятая мне не нравится, хотя правилам формально соответствует.** Но вот почему? Может быть, дело в том, что  существительное "слово" имеет неопределенное значение и поэтому воспринимается вместе с оборотом как единое целое?

Сравнить: *Слова со значением специфических национальных реалий — так называемая безэквивалентная лексика — передаются транскрипцией.* **Этот вариант симметричный.**

А вы как думаете? Нормально смотрится несимметрично оформленная вставная конструкция?

Comment: Примечание: авторы задания такой вариант ответа не предлагают.

Comment: Это новый вопрос, который  уже не рассматривает выбор того, что предлагают авторы. Что  нам в принципе даёт симметричное оформление, когда его желательно применять - вот что меня интересует. Я не могу понять, почему мне не нравится несимметричная конструкция именно в этом предложении. Образно говоря, такое впечатление, что  оно "заваливается" на один бок  и форма как-то искажает  содержание.

Comment: "Симметричный" вариант даёт лишний знак, менее обязывающий автора или корректора обосновывать, на каком грамматическом основании это делается (симметрия и всё тут! - у Розенталя зафиксировано как встречающееся в редакторской практике). Моё отношение к лишним знакам: можно не ставить - не надо ставить, дабы не навредить пытливому читателю отъёмом у него времени на анализ. Визуально обычный вариант может не нравиться при примерке к этой вставке скобок вместо тире (запятая оказывается _после_ них).

Comment: Мне не так интересны проблемы корректоров, которым надо отчитываться за знаки,  а вот проблемы читателя, которому знаки препинания помогают читать текст, мне намного ближе,   проблемы красивой графики интересны тоже. Мне кажется (вернее, я почти уверена), что Розенталь нам недосказал половину того, что знал и мог бы рассказать. Может, не успел (и так работы было много), а может быть, не захотел, так как считал, что пока ещё всё равно не поймут.  Но сейчас мы уже выросли из коротких штанишек, уже можем понять, только  вот  рассказать некому. И поэтому приходится делать  вид, что проблемы нет.